# Redefine a variable type in a subclass (i.e. variable hiding)

Tags: scala

I have googled this several different ways… but have yet to find a definitive answer.

```
class Foo1 { }
class Foo2 extends Foo1 { }

class Bar1 {
    var foo: Foo1 = null
}

class Bar2 extends Bar1 {
    var foo: Foo2 = null  // <-- compiler error
}
```

The error says: "overriding variable foo in class Bar1 of type test.Foo1;  variable foo needs `override' modifier" but you can't override the var either.

In C# you can use the new keyword like this

```
class Foo1 { }
class Foo2 : Foo1 { }

class Bar1
{
    public Foo1 foo = null;
}

class Bar2 : Bar1 
{
    public new Foo2 foo = null;
}
```

Is it possible to do this in Scala?

EDIT -- Added another C# example to show why I am doing this.

```
class Foo1 { }
class Foo2 : Foo1 { }

class Bar1
{
    public Foo1 Foo { get { return _foo; } }
    protected Foo1 _foo;
    public Bar1(Foo1 foo) { _foo = foo; }       
}

class Bar2 : Bar1
{
    public new Foo2 Foo { get { return _foo; } }
    protected new Foo2 _foo;
    public Bar2(Foo2 foo) : base(foo) { _foo = foo; }
}
```

Of course in the real app the classes are way more complex w/ many members and the hierarchy goes even deeper.

In short what this does for me is that it allows me to use the foo variable anywhere in my class hierarchy w/o having to use an ugly cast – which would be the case if I only had the single foo declared in the Bar1 class.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know C#, is `foo` assignable in your second code snippet?

Comment: @Dimitri Yes, if what you mean is say x is an instance of Bar2 then x.foo = new Foo2() is valid code… But this example is a little contrived because that’s not really how I use it in the app that I am looking at moving from C# to Scala on. I’ll either leave another message here or edit my question to explain more why/what I need it for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for covariance on a `var` attribute. That doesn't compile because it's not sound:

```
class Foo1
class Foo2 extends Foo1 {
  def moo = 42
}
class Foo3 extends Foo1

class Bar1 {
  var foo: Foo1 = null
}

class Bar2 extends Bar1 {
  var foo: Foo2 = null // Let's suppose this compiles
}    

val bar2: Bar2 = new Bar2
val bar1: Bar1 = bar2
bar1.foo = new Foo3
bar2.foo.moo
```

On the last line you call `.moo` on an instance of `Foo3` (which doesn't implement such method) but the compiler can't tell you this because `bar2.foo` is supposed to be a `Foo2`.

On a `val` however it compiles:

```
class Bar1 {
  val foo: Foo1 = new Foo1
}

class Bar2 extends Bar1 {
  override val foo: Foo2 = new Foo2
}
```

---

Update

After some tests and [reading this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691135%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), what I understand in your C# code is that you really have 2 fields in an instance of `Bar2`. When seen as `Bar1`, `x.foo` refers to the field from `Bar1`, and seen as `Bar2`, `x.foo` refers to the attribute in Bar2. And their type and even their nature (method / field / type) can be completely unrelated. I can't think of anything similar in Scala. But if I'm correct, you could as well use another name for `Bar2`'s `foo`.

---

Update 2

The following code may be what you want, if `foo` is never reassigned:

```
class Bar1(val foo: Foo1)

class Bar2(override val foo: Foo2) extends Bar1(foo)
```

Comment: Hmmm... I’ll have to study your answer a little to see if it applies to why I need this.

Comment: ahh.. yes. I think you understood correctly. In my edit I show how and why I am doing this. I am still reviewing and testing… so if I am understanding you correctly. The idea of “variable hiding” is available in C# (and I am pretty sure Java too) but not Scala?

Comment: Update 2 is interesting -- it might do the trick. I’ll try that out and other permutations.  I have not got my head around the constructor weirdness of Scala yet. I just started looking at Scala yesterday. +1 for effort. I’ll mark it the correct answer in day or two if no one else chimes in w/ a simple way to do “variable hiding” in Scala

Comment: I chose your answer correct due to the statement "I can't think of anything similar in Scala". I should have checked it a long time ago -- sorry it took this long, I had forgotten about it!

Answer (score 2):

This would normally be expressed as a type parameter or type member.

For example, collections track their underlying "representation" or implementation:

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.4/src/library/scala/collection/GenSeqLike.scala#L33

It pops up in places like:

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.4/src/library/scala/collection/LinearSeqOptimized.scala#L27

But the other question addressed by the mechanism of member hiding is a brittle type hierarchy. Classes must be designed for inheritance (Effective Java).  So the notion that a class can evolve without regard for compatibility with clients (including subclasses) is misleading.

This came up in Scala because of how private members were inherited (or not). I can't find the discussion offhand, but [in this issue](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8558) it's called the `weird "private members aren't inherited" change`. You might go, "What's weird about that?"

[This issue](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6794) might be the umbrella issue or meta-bug.

This is the case that annoys people:

```
scala> class A { val v: Int = 42 }
defined class A

scala> class B extends A { private val v: String = "42" }
<console>:8: error: overriding value v in class A of type Int;
 value v has weaker access privileges; it should not be private
       class B extends A { private val v: String = "42" }
                                       ^
```

Some have advocated for stronger privacy rights.

Comment: I like that last sentence there! Good one! +1 :) Basically it would seem to me that the decision makers controlling Scala are simply against variable hiding in subclasses. Period. Converting your two line snippet to C# verbatim `class A { public int v = 42; }` `class B : A { private string v = "42"; }` works just fine in C# (you get a warning that you’re hiding v, but just place the new keyword in there `class B : A { private new string v = "42"; }` and the warning goes away).